# Прощу помощи по jquery touch

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы контент не увеличивался на странице при масштабировании, но и работал Tap. Использую jquery toush библиотеку.

С этим кодом не работает Tap, но все остальное работает как надо при масштабировании:

```
if (options.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

А вот когда изменяю на этот код, то Tap начинает работать, но весь контент который находится на странице браузера начинает увеличивается при масштабировании.

```
// prevent default handlers
if ((options.preventTouchDefault && !isMouse) || (options.preventMouseDefault && isMouse)) {
    event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: && - этот оператор обычно используется в условиях и означает "и"... какое-то условие && другое условие... а при выполнении кода - не понятно, для чего там стоит... или я чего-то не знаю, или вы)

Comment: я пытаюсь использовать данную библиотеу http://a-fung.github.io/jQueryTouch/